# How can I recover my files from my computer with corrupted hard disk drive?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, system-restore, hard-drive-recovery, filesystem-corruption

**My HP 250G3 computer can't boot and instead says:**

> Boot Device Not Found
>   Please install an operating system on your hard disk.
>   Hard Disk (3F0)
>   F2 System Diagnostics
>
> For more information, please visit: www.hp.com/go/techcenter/startup

That's all. The hard disk test passed. I found that I will need to hard reset the computer and/or reinstall my OS. That would *destroy* my files, which i need - I had some long-term projects going.
**I would like to:**
1) **recover** ALL files (*.avi* files not important) - about 600GB of data, ±200GB, wich is more than the LAN storage if I don't throw the .avi files (about 150GB)
2) get **my computer working** with Windows 8, any version (not Win 10)
3) have my files back on my computer
4) not pay anything

**What I have:**
- the broken computer - standard technical parameters, had Windows 8.1
- an **old Linux Fedora computer** with lesser parameters and Wine Windows program loader installed, and about **100GB** free
- a Windows 7 computer with no space available (2MB free)
- a **32GB flash disk** with no needed data on it
- possibly even a 2nd flash disk with 8GB
- a stack of 700MB **CD's**
- a **local web storage** with important data on it, but with **500GB** free
- **Internet** connection
I can also access the **library computers with ubuntu**, buy a DVD or do anything needed (if it's cheap).

**What I see possible:**
1) Installing Win 8.x on the computer **without** deleting any files or formatting the HDD,
OR
2) Copying **every** file to local storage **except the .avi files**, then hard resetting the computer and copynig the files back.
I tried botting the computer with "safe mode" and simmilar stuff, nothing works.

Does anybody have any easy and preferably **step-by-step** ("for dummies") **way of getting my computer back with (all) data?** I was searching online (including stackoverflow) and tried/read many ways of stuff, but evry single one was out of my options and/or had a problem or error. I would like to find a way of **recovering my files** and getting back to work on my computer again. I'm not a computer expert, I don't understand these thing much, so the more steps you cut your answer, the better for me.
**Please do not hate or close this question, it's my last hope.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buy an IDE/SATA adapter that connects your hard disk to any USB port as an 'external' hard disk for about 15 $. See picture for an *example*.

With that you can remove the hard disk from your current computer and connected to any other Machine to back up your files.

Afterwards, you can reinstall your Windows; if you're lucky, your files are all still there anyway; otherwise you repeat the exercise and simply copy them all back.

[image]

Comment: Is there ANY way to access the HDD through an USB and then copying some of the files to the cloud storage using **only** the USB, and some software?

Comment: Yes with right that cable. I added a photo.

Comment: Super! Just here in the Czech republic its for ~20$. Didn't find this solution anyware else. Also, why the -1 (not that I would hate you for it)?

Comment: I did not give the -1

Answer (score 1):

3F0 can be caused by 3 things

1. Bad hard drive or partition structure, erase the entire hard drive then use HP recovery discs to attempt reinstall of the OS and all partitions.
2. Bad hard drive data cable that connects it to the motherboard, replace the cable
3. Bad sata controller on the motherboard replaces the motherboard or laptop.

[Source](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Re-quot-Hard-Disk-3F0-BootDevice-not-found-quot-Error/m-p/5469074#M323474)

If you suspect a bad cable or motherboard, do as Aganju suggested and put the drive in a sata enclosure to salvage your data.

Comment: I tried accesing the HDD from an Ubuntu stick, and it shows the files, but doesn't want to copy them.

Comment: And also, I already was on that page, read it.